# raise ChunkedEncodingError(e) requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(1546 bytes read, 6646 more expected)'

Tags: python, api, exception, download, python-requests

I am downloading a csv file from Restful API of salesforce. 
If the size of file increase it shows

Response headers are:

```
{
    'Expect-CT': 'max-age=86400; report-uri="a.forcesslreports.com******/######";',
    'Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only': '"#####"; pin-sha256="&&&&&&&&"; pin-sha256="@@@@@@"; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="a.forcesslreports.com/@@@@/#####";',
    'X-Robots-Tag': 'none',
    'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
    'Set-Cookie': 'BrowserId=#########;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2019 10:52:32 GMT;Max-Age=5184000',
    'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains',
    'Sforce-Limit-Info': 'api-usage=22/500',
    'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private',
    'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 10:52:32 GMT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octetstream',
    'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'
}
```

```
raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ('Connection broken: IncompleteRead(1546 bytes read, 6646 more expected)', IncompleteRead(1546 bytes read, 6646 more expected))
```

I am not getting why the connection is getting broke and how to fix it

```
def download_file(url, header):
    local_filename = url.split('/')[-2]
    with requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=header) as r:
        r.raise_for_status()
        print("in get")
        with open(local_filename+".csv", 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024*8): 
                #print("in for loop of chunk")
                if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                    f.write(chunk)
                    #f.flush()
    r.close()
    return local_filename
```

Comment: What are response headers?

Comment: {'Expect-CT': 'max-age=86400; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/******/######";', 'Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only': "#####"; pin-sha256="&&&&&&&&"; pin-sha256="@@@@@@"; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/@@@@/#####";', 'X-Robots-Tag': 'none', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Set-Cookie': 'BrowserId=#########;Path=/;Domain=.salesforce.com;Expires=Sat, 31-Aug-2019 10:52:32

Comment: GMT;Max-Age=5184000', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains', 'Sforce-Limit-Info': 'api-usage=22/500', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private', 'Date': 'Tue, 02 Jul 2019 10:52:32 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/octetstream', 'Expires': 'Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT'}

Comment: please add it to question; it's hard to read it in comments

Comment: added in question